# how to properly write a complete css3 selector to querySelectorAll

Tags: css, css-selectors, selectors-api

how to properly write this css3 selector query?

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-datasource='ds1']:not(input[type='button']):not(input[type='submit']):not(input[type='submit']):not(input[type='hidden']):not(input[type='reset']):not(input[type='file']):not(input[type='image']):not(input[type='search'])");
```

the query above throws an syntax error.

i want to select all elements that have data-datasource='ds1' excepts inputs of types button,submit,submit,hidden,reset,file,image and search.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you might need to say `*[data-source=blah]` that is, put an asterisk before the selector.

Comment: You have `:not(input[type='submit'])` duplicated in your selector.

Comment: @Will: The asterisk is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [CSS3's `:not()` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) only allows a single simple selector at a time. You're getting an exception because all your `:not(input[...])` selectors are invalid CSS3, since they contain two simple selectors: `input`, and an attribute selector.

Try this instead:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-datasource='ds1']:not(input), input[data-datasource='ds1']:not([type='button']):not([type='submit']):not([type='hidden']):not([type='reset']):not([type='file']):not([type='image']):not([type='search'])");
```

Since it's still a really long selector string, here's a breakdown:

```
/* Any elements except input that have this attribute value */
[data-datasource='ds1']:not(input), 

/* Only inputs that have this attribute value, but not any of these types */
input[data-datasource='ds1']:not([type='button']):not([type='submit']):not([type='hidden']):not([type='reset']):not([type='file']):not([type='image']):not([type='search'])
```

Comment: Great !!! I used the first query. It works wonderfull ! I think axecuting second and third queryes and them combine the results will be slower than execute first query. By this way I used your first solution. thanks again.

Comment: The second and third ones are actually the same as the first... just an explanation of how it works. Anyway you can click the tick on the left of the answer to mark it accepted as a way of saying thanks :)